# I think i did correct with scanf... but it brought C4477 and crashed

Tags: c, function, calculator, fare

I've never seen such compile error ever.
And what is int*?
The error says %d need int* not just int
I used %d as followed by int var... but what should i do with int*?

```
int main()
{
    int hour, min, car;

    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n주차요금 계산 프로그램\n");
    
    printf("\n주차 시간을 입력하세요.\n\n   시간:\n");
    scanf("%d",hour);
    
    printf("\n   분:\n");
    scanf("%d", min);

    printf("\n%d시간 %d분\n", hour, min);
    printf("\n당신의 차종은 무엇입니까?\n");
    printf("\n 1.경차   2.기타\n");
    scanf("%d", car);
```

Comment: What does the declaration of `hour` look like? `int hour;`? Then use `scanf("%d", &hour);`.

Comment: @Sunfare1944 - Where did you learn that you can pass the variable by value to `scanf`?

Comment: Don't worry about what `int *` means for now.  It just means you need to use `&` on most of the variables you fill in with `scanf`.  Everything except strings.

Comment: C is pass-by-value: the parameters to `scanf` are copied, and have the lifetime of that function. For this reason, there is no way to directly return a parameter; you have to pass it's memory address. With strings, you are already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` needs a pointer as its second argument.

```
int main()
{
    int hour, min, car;

    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n주차요금 계산 프로그램\n");
    
    printf("\n주차 시간을 입력하세요.\n\n   시간:\n");
    scanf("%d",&hour);
    
    printf("\n   분:\n");
    scanf("%d", &min);

    printf("\n%d시간 %d분\n", hour, min);
    printf("\n당신의 차종은 무엇입니까?\n");
    printf("\n 1.경차   2.기타\n");
    scanf("%d", &car);
}
```

You will learn why when you study pointers. For now, just remember to put this `&` operator before the variable.